# Making a program to find what the longest substring in alphabetical order

Tags: python, helper, edx

I want to write a program that prints the longest sub string in alphabetical order from the string s and I don't know what I am doing wrong, I just started coding a few days ago and this is the best I've come up with.

```
s = 'vvrsmxxlplnawxxcmcvuxrgi'

alphabet =['a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j','k','l','m','n','o','p','q','r','s','t','u','v','w','x','y','z']
Current_Sequence=''
Max_Sequence=''
runs=0
current_runs = ''
max_runs=''
for I in str(s)[1:]:
    runs +=1
    if alphabet.index(I) >= alphabet.index(s[runs-1]):
        Current_Sequence += str(I)
        current_runs += str(runs)
    else:
        if (len(str(Current_Sequence))) > (len(str(Max_Sequence))) :
            Max_Sequence = str(Current_Sequence)
            Current_Sequence=''
            max_runs= int(str(current_runs)[0])
            current_runs=''
        else: 
            Current_Sequence=''
            current_runs=''

if (len(Max_Sequence)) >= (len(Current_Sequence)):
    print('Longest substring in alphabetical order is: ' + s[max_runs-1] + str(Max_Sequence))

if (len(Current_Sequence)) > (len(Max_Sequence)):
    print('Longest substring in alphabetical order is: ' + s[current_runs[0]-1] + str(Current_Sequence))
```

*** ERROR: Expected 'awxx', got 'vwxx'. ***

in another trial where s = 'zyxwvutsrqponmlkjihgfedcba' the result was
*** ERROR: Expected 'z', got 'unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'str' and 'int''. ***

any input will help, as I am young and very new to code

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow!  Is your code not working as intended?  If not, could you edit your post and describe what it is doing?

Comment: Welcome! Can you provide some examples of desired results?

Comment: Please read: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example - What is your input? You have:`for I in str(s)[1:]:`, but I don't see `s` defined anywhere. What is the output you get? What output were you expecting? Show some test cases and that'll be a good starting point...

Comment: As @DillonMiller mentioned. can you please provide some example input values and the results that you would expect.

Please explain also what's wrong with the code, that you tried out.
If you get an error message, then please post it as well in your question.

The more information you give us, the higher are the chances to get a good answer

Comment: I just did as recommended and added in the input for the string s, the expected output and actual output

Comment: What is the idea behind the variable max_runs? That's the issue here. Line 17 to be exact.

Comment: I was using the variable max_runs on that line to track the index value of the beginning of the sequence, so I can add it to the final print

Answer (score 2):

You don't have to change very much.

Just a few lines:

You want to start at the first character

```
for I in str(s)[0:]:
```

As soon as the sequence restarts you also want to add the current letter - that broke the chain - to your new sequence. Therefore you don't need max_runs anymore

```
Current_Sequence=I
```

Move the runs +=1 to the end of the for loop.

Remove max_runs from the print

```
print('Longest substring in alphabetical order is: ' + str(Max_Sequence))
```

Full code:

```
s = 'kjddbyydx'
alphabet =['a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j','k','l','m','n','o','p','q','r','s','t','u','v','w','x','y','z']
Current_Sequence=''
Max_Sequence=''
runs=0
for I in str(s)[0:]:
    if alphabet.index(I) >= alphabet.index(s[runs-1]):
        Current_Sequence += str(I)
    else:
        if (len(str(Current_Sequence))) > (len(str(Max_Sequence))) :
            Max_Sequence = str(Current_Sequence)
            Current_Sequence=I
        else:
            Current_Sequence = I
    runs +=1

if (len(Max_Sequence)) >= (len(Current_Sequence)):
    print('Longest substring in alphabetical order is: ' + str(Max_Sequence))

if (len(Current_Sequence)) > (len(Max_Sequence)):
    print('Longest substring in alphabetical order is: ' + str(Current_Sequence))
```

Code using enumerate instead of a for loop:

```
for runs, I in enumerate(s):
    if alphabet.index(I) >= alphabet.index(s[runs-1]):
        Current_Sequence += str(I)
    else:
        if (len(str(Current_Sequence))) > (len(str(Max_Sequence))) :
            Max_Sequence = str(Current_Sequence)
            Current_Sequence=I
        else:
            Current_Sequence = I

if (len(Max_Sequence)) >= (len(Current_Sequence)):
    print('Longest substring in alphabetical order is: ' + str(Max_Sequence))

if (len(Current_Sequence)) > (len(Max_Sequence)):
    print('Longest substring in alphabetical order is: ' + str(Current_Sequence))
```

Comment: Could you show me how I would apply this to my program, again I am very new and have A LOT to learn.

Comment: You can get rid of current_run as well. Just updated code, it is not necessary anymore.

Comment: Works for me, it gives the correct output. But I changed the code once more. Should do as you wish now, I guess.

Comment: Nevermind. Your adjustment worked like a charm. Could you explain what you changed and why it was wrong. Thank you for the help.

Comment: Don't know anymore. But I would like to give you an advice. You used the for-loop and inside you use "runs" to store the index of the char you're current looking at. Try using enumerate, like so:
     for runs, I in enumerate(s):

Comment: What does the command enumerate do? I am taking an introductory course and I haven't heard of it yet, so I didn't know it was an option, but I will keep it in mind from now on.

Comment: If you loop over the string as you did, you just get the char at the current iteration of the loop. Like in "abc" you would get "a", then "b", then "c". But you dont know the position if you dont keep track of it using "runs". But if you use "for index, I in enumerate(s)" you will loop over s and get the index and the char every time. Like "0, a", then "1, b", then "2, c".

Comment: Just updated the answer, there is code using enumerate now. Just as an example

Answer (score 0):

you program looks ok.  maybe this will help you to trace what is wrong

```
    def max_substr(s):
        max_s = s[0:1]
        cur_s = max_s

        for i in range(1, len(s)):
            ch = s[i : i + 1]
            if ch >= cur_s[-1]:
                cur_s = cur_s + ch
                if len(cur_s) > len(max_s):
                    max_s = cur_s
            else:
                cur_s = ch

        return max_s


    print(max_substr("vvrsmxxlplnawxxcmcvuxrgi"))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use zip to offset the string by one, accumulate the substrings, and select the longest one.

```
s = 'vvrsmxxlplnawxxcmcvuxrgi'

li = []
st = ""
for c1,c2 in zip(s,s[1:]):
    if c2 >= c1:
        st += c1
    elif st != "":
        li.append(st+c1)
        st =""

print(max(li, key = len))
```

Output:

```
awxx
```